# Vertical align a label inside btn-group using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I have 2 `inline elements` inside a horizontal form and I can't vertical align the labels . Is there a clean way to do it without using hacks like display:table ?

Here is the **code** i tried so far: **[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/OmarIsComing/bK3ioLqca6)**

Comment: Those 2 elements needs to be inline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add line-height css to the label and match it with the height of the button

new css:

```
.btn-group label{
   line-height: 35px;
}
```

since the .btn-group is 35px high, you make line height 35px as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Use** the new **[CSS3 Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** display property.

It's easy and **works** perfect in every scenario.

```
.btn-group{
   ....
   display:inline-flex;
   justify-content:center;
}

.btn-group label{
   ....
   align-self:center;
   margin-bottom:0px;
}
```